# Difference between two consecutive rows by ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get the difference between two consecutive rows by ID, the two dates are in different columns.  I'm thinking it would have to be something with PARTITION BY combined with getting a MAX 2 desc, then grabbing a MAX 1 asc... getting a bit confused by the logic though.  Here is a sample.

**Before**

```
ID  Start_date  End_date
1   1/1/2017    2/8/2017
1   2/10/2017   3/8/2017
1   3/21/2017   3/29/2017
1   4/11/2017   5/12/2017
2   4/2/2016    4/3/2016
2   4/6/2016    5/11/2016
3   4/25/2016   4/30/2016
3   5/25/2016   6/29/2016
3   7/13/2016   7/15/2016
3   7/18/2016   8/24/2016
```

**AFTER**

```
ID  Start_date  End_date    new
1   1/1/2017    2/8/2017    NULL
1   2/10/2017   3/8/2017    2
1   3/21/2017   3/29/2017   13
1   4/11/2017   5/12/2017   13
2   4/2/2016    4/3/2016    NULL
2   4/6/2016    5/11/2016   3
3   4/25/2016   4/30/2016   NULL
3   5/25/2016   6/29/2016   25
3   7/13/2016   7/15/2016   14
3   7/18/2016   8/24/2016   3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [the `lag` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to get the previous value and use it in `datediff`.

```
select t.*,datediff(day,lag(end_date) over(partition by id order by start_date),start_date) as diff
from tbl t
```

> LAG provides access to a row at a given physical offset that comes before the current row. Use this analytic function in a SELECT statement to compare values in the current row with values in a previous row.

Comment: LAG is nondeterministic. Make sure that your over() clause will return the same set in the same order every execution, or you will get unpredictable results.
There are only very specific circumstances in which to use LAG. See the comments at the end of the function documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017