# pyspark: calculate consecutive difference by ID

Tags: pyspark

My question is exactly as [Difference between two consecutive rows by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51073237/difference-between-two-consecutive-rows-by-id) but for pyspark.

I have a dataframe

```
ID value
1  2
1 3
1 5
2 4
2 9
```

And I want to calculate the `lag` of `value` based on `ID`, so:

```
ID value_lag
1 1
1 2
2 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Window` function to calculate the difference as in `sql`,

```
>>> df.show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|    2|
|  1|    3|
|  1|    5|
|  2|    4|
|  2|    9|
+---+-----+

>>> from pyspark.sql import Window
>>> cnd = F.col('value') - F.lag('value').over(w)
>>> df.select('id',cnd.name('value_lag')).dropna().show()
+---+---------+
| id|value_lag|
+---+---------+
|  1|        1|
|  1|        2|
|  2|        5|
+---+---------+
```

Comment: what does `window` function do?

Comment: Check this, https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html